# Pass value from Hashcorp keyvault into application.yml file

Tags: spring-boot, hashicorp

Load hashicorp key vault values into my application.yml file in Spring boot

Answer (score 0):

To pass values from HashiCorp Vault into the application.yml file of a Spring Boot application, you can use Spring Cloud Vault. Spring Cloud Vault provides integration with HashiCorp Vault and allows you to retrieve secrets from Vault and inject them into your Spring application context.